# gRPC tracing on Android

Tags: android, grpc, grpc-java

I am trying to see detailed logs from gRPC to troubleshoot an issue I'm having as described [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md)

However, I can't get it to work on Android. I have tried adding this in my `Application.onCreate`:

```
Os.setenv("GRPC_TRACE", "all", true)
Os.setenv("GRPC_VERBOSITY", "DEBUG", true)
```

Answer (score 0):

gRPC on Android is provided by the [grpc-java](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java) project, which does not look at those environment variables. The page you linked is for gRPC C-core, which has wrappers for a few languages (C++, Python, PHP, a few others), but not Java/Android.

For Java, I believe you can change the default logging level in your `logging.properties` file, something like:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
io.grpc.level=FINEST
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST
```